Is there a way to use Logs Explorer to retrieve the configuration settings of a deleted data transfer?
About a week ago, I accidentally deleted the wrong data transfer and I'm trying to see how to recreate it. I realize that deleting a data transfer can't be undone, but I was hoping I could maybe use Logs Explorer to find past instances of the data transfer being run and access the deleted transfer's configuration settings through there, and then create a new data transfer with identical settings. Does anyone know if this is possible? If not, is there any other way to get this data transfer back? I would try to recreate it from memory but I didn't make this transfer so I'm not entirely sure what it was designed to do in the first place.
I've tried to use the link to the deleted data transfer and of course this yielded no results since the settings for it are no longer saved anywhere, and I've also tried to use the following command to retrieve past data transfers but got no results either.
resource.type="bigquery_resource" AND log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access") AND proto_payload.method_name="jobservice.jobcompleted"
I also read you can retrieve deleted tables but not sure if that's applicable. Thank you in advance for your help.
